# JsonConvert - guid string deserialized as default guid

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, guid

I am serializing a DTO class with a string and guid properties.

It gets converted into string just fine, but when I deserialize the property back to an object, the Guid property is a default guid.

I can see the string being correct and this object has literally just been serialized into string, so does it mean Newtonsoft's Json converter does not handle it by default?

[image]

Comment: Show your `UploadedFile` class

Comment: Should work by default. Check `FileGuid` property - it should be public and have a setter.

Comment: @IllyaChumakov - Bool's eye :) The setter was internal

Comment: In that case, see related [JSON deserialize to constructed protected setter array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25950112/3744182).