# IdentityResult can't deserialized to a model over aspnet core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, asp.net-core

I want to use some identity methods over WebApi like change password.

This is the identity result:

```
public class IdentityResult
{
    public IdentityResult();
    public static IdentityResult Success { get; }
    public bool Succeeded { get; protected set; }
    public IEnumerable<IdentityError> Errors { get; }
    public static IdentityResult Failed(params IdentityError[] errors);
    public override string ToString();
}
```

If it used on a Ok() ActionResult we have an error ,because it has ReferenceLoop. For this reason I create a custom IdentityResult like this :

```
public class CustomIdentityResult
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; protected set; }
    public List<IdentityError> Errors { get; }
}
```

and send the real action result like this :

```
        var model = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, currentPassword, newPassword);
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });

        return Ok(result);
```

It return an string like this :

```
"{\n  \"Succeeded\": true,\n  \"Errors\": []\n}"
```

But after deserialize this string :

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomIdentityResult>(response.Content);
```

it return Succeeded = false and errors = null.
Even if I have some errors and Succeeded = false ,it return Succeeded = false and errors = null again.

Where is deserialize problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `Succeeded` has a protected setter so you need to mark it with `[JsonProperty]` as shown in [JSON deserialize to constructed protected setter array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25950535/3744182).  `Errors` has no setter at all so you will need to either add a protected setter or pre-allocate a `List<IdentityError>` for its value in the constructor.

Comment: @dbc thanks a lot! it works like a charm (y)